# Using Emacs to format existing HTML+JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, emacs

I've downloaded web-mode.el and load it via .emacs. That works fine. I loaded an HTML+JavaScript file (i.e., I "wget" www.google.com).

Now I want to format this blob of HTML+JavaScript. Not apparent how to select the entire file and format it? Both HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: `M-x indent-region`.

Answer (score 0):

You should hit `C-x h` and then `TAB`